# SwaggerUI authorization with Google and Identity System

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, swagger, google-oauth, swagger-ui

Good day all,

I'm trying to build a headless API that can be interacted with using Swagger. I've managed to successfully integrate Google login using Swaggers Authorize button. I can see swagger appending a Bearer token to all my requests. However, when I inspect `User.Identity` in my controller, all the fields are null. Some help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

I would like to offload user management to Google and just use public profile details from Google itself.

Here's Program.cs

```
using DataAccess.EFCore;
using DataAccess.EFCore.Repositories;
using Domain.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Reflection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<MyDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB"),
        options => options.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyDBContext).Assembly.FullName)
    )
);

builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["GoogleOAuth:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["GoogleOAuth:ClientSecret"];
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    });

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
{
    swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "MyAPI,
        Description = "MyAPI"
    });

    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    swagger.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));

    swagger.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "email" }, { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "profile" } }
            },
        }
    });

    swagger.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "oauth2"
                }
            },
            new List<string>{"email", "profile"}
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.DisplayRequestDuration();
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI V1");
        options.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["GoogleOAuth:ClientId"]);
        options.OAuthClientSecret(builder.Configuration["GoogleOAuth:ClientSecret"]);
        options.OAuthAppName("MyAPI");
    });
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
} 
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.MapControllers();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

Some screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From your image , we can see the  `IsAuthenticated` is `false`, so all the fields are null. Check with your authorization account.

Comment: The oauth with google worked but as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982278/swagger-with-google-oauth-2-0-authorization) have noted the response is not quite what we need. I ended up implementing [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193993/authentication-with-google-in-web-api-and-swagger) which is working okay. I'm leaving the question up though to see if anyone knows how to get it working with Identity directly.